# Installing FreeBSD alongside Linux

Tags: linux, boot, freebsd, dual-boot, uefi

I am using Arch Linux with GNOME, I want to install FreeBSD alongside Arch Linux with the following requirements :

- I want to keep the Linux GRUB and add an entry of FreeBSD to it.
- I want to use different **SWAP** partitions for Linux and BSD.
- I Do not want to Destroy my Linux /boot

My System Information :

- I am using Arch Linux : **UEFI** mode.
- Disk is GPT
- My partition Layout Looks like this :

  [image]

.

```
[severus@Tux ~]$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name       Flags
 1      1049kB  1076MB  1075MB  fat32           ESP        boot, esp
 2      1076MB  76.2GB  75.2GB  ext4            root
 3      76.2GB  125GB   48.3GB  ext4            home
 4      125GB   134GB   9837MB  linux-swap(v1)  swap
 5      134GB   564GB   429GB   ext4
 6      564GB   832GB   268GB   ext4
 7      832GB   914GB   82.0GB  ext4
 8      973GB   1000GB  26.8GB  ext4            CZ-Backup
```

- I wish to install FreeBSD on the Un-allocated space preceding **`/dev/sda8`**

---

To be more precise, I am  stuck at partitioning during the FreeBSD Installation process. i.e,  In the Documentation, It is said that FreeBSD uses specific types of partitions ( `freebsd-boot, freebsd-ufs, freebsd-swap`) .

Is `freebsd-boot` same as **EFI-System-Partition ?** , Should I create a new `freebsd-boot` or is there any way to use the existing **Linux-ESP**?

---

I got some relevant threads, but they seems to be out-dated :

- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=111660

Comment: It may be outdated, but FreeBSD likes to be in its own partition and slice *that* up.  Its [documentation for partitioning](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/bsdinstall-partitioning.html) gives an overview of GPT, but does not address your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can install FreeBSD alongside any linux distro with the following requirements :

> - I want to keep the Linux GRUB and add an entry of FreeBSD to it.
> - I want to use different SWAP partitions for Linux and BSD.
> - I Do not want to Destroy my Linux /boot

You need to create 3 partitions : `swap`: (4G) , `/boot` (512K) and the `/` partition.

To create the boot partition:

Choose Create :

- Type : `freebsd-boot`
- Size : `512k`
- Label `boot`

To create the swap partition :

- Type : `freebsd-swap`
- Size : `4G`
- Label : `swap`

To create the root partition:

- Type : `freebsd-ufs`
- Size: `keep it unchanged`
- Mount point : `/`
- Label : `root`

Choose `finish` then select `Commit` to start the installation and hit `Enter`.

Once the installation is done reboot into `arch-linux` , open the `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` file then add the new entry:

```
menuentry "FreeBSD" {
    insmod ufs2
    set root=(hd0,gpt8)
    kfreebsd /boot/loader
}
```

Run:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Reboot into Freebsd to install Xorg , Desktop ...

> Is freebsd-boot same as EFI-System-Partition ? , Should I create a new freebsd-boot or is there any way to use the existing Linux-ESP?

You should create a new `freebsd-boot` partition , if you forget to add it , the installer will ask you for adding the `boot` partition automatically.

Comment: Thank you :) I was about to some how try using the existing /boot (ESP) thinking that it will understand everything automatically as it happens in Linux-Linux dual-boot.

Comment: Oh..no!  I booted into BSD and I am not seeing my free space at all !!! , only "linux-disk" (sth like that) .

Comment: @SeverusTux Did you mean you can't mount the `ext4` partitions?

Comment: No, I mean I am not able to make partitions during the installation. It is showing : "linux-data" on all the partitions and "linux-swap" on the swap. Even if I delete one of the partitions, it does not show me the free space from which I could have created required partitions. (I am trying to install freeBSD 10.3)

Comment: From Arch Linux format it as ext4 , Swap.... partition, reboot into Freebsd then re-recreate FreeBSD partitions.

Comment: okay, I will try that now :)