# How to dual boot FreeBSD and Linux on the same Hard disk?

Tags: linux, freebsd, grub2, dual-boot, zfs

I tried installing FreeBSD 12 release version on my system which already had 3 Linux OS installed. 
It was the minimal install iso image. My internal HDD with GPT partition table. I tried using the ZFS file system for the FreeBSD and GRUB2 bootloader configured from the first OS which is Arch Linux. Didn't know about  this issue with Linux system and GRUB not supporting/recognising  ZFS file system by default. GRUB wouldn't recognise ZFS file system and hence wouldn't boot it. While trying some tweaks from the Grub Shell to boot FreeBSD I ended up wiping my hard disk.

Edit: Whàt is the best way to dual boot Linux and FreeBSD on the same Hard disk preferably with GRUB2 bootloader ? 
Emphasis being on the  file system for FreeBSD in a such a scenario.

Comment: A [brief search](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdual-boot%5D+freebsd+linux) on U&L brings this: [Installing FreeBSD alongside Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309964/installing-freebsd-alongside-linux). No zfs, though. I understand your frustration but, please, try editing your question to make it more focused around a single issue — many questions wrapped in a single paragraph are unlikely to be effectively answered. You may prefer to leave some of your points for later: narrow questions may get answers pretty fast, and you may ask as many questions as you like.

Comment: @fra-san - It is possible to install Linux and FreeBSD alongside each other - https://ericmccorkleblog.wordpress.com/2016/11/15/cohabiting-freebsd-and-gentoo-linux-on-a-common-zfs-volume/ - It will require using a distribution that has the ZOL packages and a way to allow manual customization on the installation process. Besides that, this question seems to be to be way too broad and opinion based, and with 3 Linux OSs installed, there is a big chance all primary partitions got depleted. Also, using ZFS or not highly depends on the hardware being used, familiarity with the fs and purpose

Comment: @nwildner Sorry, poor wording by me: "no zfs" meant that I wasn't able to easily find a dual-boot FreeBSD + Linux Q/A here on U&L that _also_ mentioned zfs. I agree on the "too broad" part and was hoping the OP were willing to prune it and choose one single, specific issue to start with.

Comment: Welome , The must important part , Grub should be installed and managed from FreeBSD.

Comment: @fra-san wow that looks normal! Now that raises other questions which I will post later. UFS looks manageable . One reason I went with ZFS was that it is being compared with btrfs and have managed btrfs in Linux.

Comment: @nwildner , the set up in link looks too 'no-newbie-zone'. I guess I need to understand ZFS properly  first  to try that. Or perhaps look for a more simple set up.

Comment: @GAD3R that's exactly what I have been hearing and reading on the net. That fact that ZFS' license doesn't comply with GNU GPL is what this whole scenario is about. Because of this conflict GNU/Linux can't import ZFS natively to the kernel. But people are clever , they have come up with various workaround and lend support to ZFS which turned out haphazard (as in my case ). The GRUB bootloader from most Linux distros (I have known  the issue being reported in Fedora,gentoo,l and arch ).